# How to search in local time with a Python Script?

Tags: python, twitter, timezone

I have a script with TwitterSearch using different variables, so that I can convert the retrieved tweets in local time.

However, when I try to add the set_until condition, it begins to search at 8pm instead of midnight (the difference between UTC and my timezone). Can I force it to begin 4 hours later?

Here are the relevant portions of my code :

```
from time import strftime
from email.utils import parsedate, parsedate_tz, mktime_tz
from datetime import datetime, date
import pytz
```

The timestamp conversion

```
timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz(tweet_time_string))
return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The search criteria

```
tso.set_until(date(2015,04,18))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: it looks like there are unnecessary conversions in your code. Why do you [convert the time to string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29147941/4279) if the input for `set_until` is `date()` object? Is your question how to convert `tweet_time_string` to `date()` object?(call `.date()` instead of `.strftime()`)  Provide a specific example of the input and the expected output (including types). Mention what timezone `tso.set_until()` expects. Is it UTC or your local timezone (whatever it is)?

Comment: In fact, the timestamp conversion is to fill a csv with preformatted data, while the search criteria is to circumscribe the search.

And I would like to set tso.set_until() to my local timezone (EST).

Comment: The code from [`to_local_time()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29151067/4279) is unrelated to your question. Remove it (unless there is some connection between `tweet_time_string` and `date(2015, 4, 18)`). Is your question: how to convert time in your local timezone to UTC?

Comment: My question is how to set tso.set_until on local time, because it begins to retrieve tweets at 19:59 instead of 23:59. But I need the other portion of my code to encode the tweets in local time.

Comment: If `tso.set_until()` accepts UTC time then you should convert your local time to UTC. Try whether it accepts `datetime` objects, not just `date` objects